# How do I make a copy of an SQL Server database and connect to it?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm working on vb.NET 2013 and SQL server 2008R2.

I have this situation to resolve:

I have a database "DB1". I want to create a copy of this database on the same SQL server with another name "DB2", and after make this database ready to connect.

How can I do this through code from Vb.NET?

Comment: Is the original database live, or is it an offline "template" database?

Comment: Data and structure or just structure?

Comment: The original database is an offline template database.

Comment: The original database has no data

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tech net link for restore with new file names.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190447(v=sql.105).aspx.

1. Take a backup of database one (DB1).
2. Verify backup is valid.
3. Get correct logical and physical file names
4. Restore with a move command to create database two (DB2).
5. Change ownership to SA. Defaults to SQL login that creates the database

Here is a script that I tested on my laptop. Nice thing about backup is no need for down time. If you decide to take off line, copy data files, and create database for attach, down time is created.

```
-- Sample database
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO

-- 1 - Make a backup
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
TO DISK = 'C:\mssql\backup\AdventureWorks2012.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2012';
GO


-- Use master
USE master
GO

-- 2 - Is the backup valid
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\mssql\backup\AdventureWorks2012.Bak';
GO

-- 3 - Check the logical / physical file names
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\mssql\backup\AdventureWorks2012.Bak';
GO

-- 4 - Restore the files change the location and name
RESTORE DATABASE Adv2012
   FROM DISK = 'C:\mssql\backup\AdventureWorks2012.Bak'
   WITH RECOVERY,
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 'c:\mssql\data\MyAdvWorks_Data.mdf', 
   MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' TO 'c:\mssql\log\MyAdvWorks_Data.ldf';
GO

-- 5 - Switch owner to system admin
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::Adv2012 TO SA;
GO
```

Comment: We had a vendor attempt this but didn't allow for us to determine the location of the backup copy of a HUGE database. They sent it to C: and we ran out of space bringing the server down. Just saying....

Comment: If you are using 2008 R2, make sure the compression option is used.  How big is the backup?  You can even use and external 4 TB drive.  It will be slow but you can move it from site A to site B.  Again, there is only a few options (BACKUP, FILE COPY).  Issue with file copy is no compression.  In short, the above TSQL is a correct answer.  Just change the location.  I have used it dozens of times.

Comment: I agree - I use the same method to move a snapshot copy of a database to tablets for field use. The disconnected tablets run the same app as the desktop pointed to the Express SQL Server. All I was saying is one should be careful about putting stuff on the drive hosting the OS unless you know you will do no harm.

Comment: @rheitzman Point taking.  Again, most code I donate to the community comes from my laptop that only has one drive (C:).  On a production system, I would probably be backing up over the network to a backup system that has a ton of inexpensive disk space.  It is a reality that most database systems are installed improperly.  IE - all databases on drive C:.  CYL