# SQL query to backup a database returns error when executed as a SqlCommand from code

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

The following **SQL query** was modified from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462198) and it runs properly in SSMS. My objective is to keep an updated database copy that serves as a backup and is readily available in the server to be accessed from code.

```
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu] SET ONLINE;
DROP DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu]

USE [conf.HelpDb];
BACKUP DATABASE [conf.HelpDb]
TO DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
       MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups',
       NAME = 'Full Backup of conf.HelpDb';

USE master
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak';
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak';

RESTORE DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu]
   FROM DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak'
   WITH RECOVERY,
   MOVE 'conf.HelpDb' TO 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf.HelpDb.mdf', 
   MOVE 'conf.HelpDb_log' TO 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf.HelpDb_log.ldf';

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[conf.HelpDbBu] TO SA;
GO
```

Not being certain of the best way to execute this query from code, I settled on running an SQL command using a SqlConnection.  The following **code** works: (certain parts are currently hard coded that will be changed after the bugs are ironed out)

```
        Public Shared Function ExecuteSQLCommand()

        Dim commandText = "USE master;" &
            "ALTER DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;" &
            "ALTER DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu] SET ONLINE;" &
            "DROP DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu]" &
            "USE [conf.HelpDb];" &
            "BACKUP DATABASE [conf.HelpDb]" &
            "TO DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak'" &
            "With Format," &
            "MEDIANAME = 'SQLServerBackups'," &
            "NAME = 'Full Backup of conf.HelpDb';" &
            "RESTORE DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu]" &
            "From DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak'" &
            "With RECOVERY," &
            "MOVE 'conf.HelpDb' TO 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf.HelpDb.mdf', " &
            "MOVE 'conf.HelpDb_log' TO 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf.HelpDb_log.ldf';" &
            "ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE:: [conf.HelpDbBu] TO SA;"

        Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HelpDbConnection").ConnectionString)
            Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(commandText, connection)
            command.Connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        Return 1
    End Function
```

The connection string is:

```
connectionString="Data Source=<my pcname>\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=conf.HelpDb;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But the original query included the following lines:

```
USE master
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
From DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak';
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
From DISK = 'C:\tfsCollateral\_projects\conf\dbBackups\conf_HelpDb.Bak';
```

The lines above errored out with the following message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Database 'masterRESTORE' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.'
```

I added a colon to the first line above making it `USE master;`.  But now I have the following error and I am unable to see the problem.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'DISK'.'
```

The purpose of the RESTORE FILELISTONLY wasn't perfectly clear to me, but I presumed it was to find out the exact filenames in the `.Bak` file to be restored so the subsequent RESTORE DATABASE command could be properly populated.

While the vb.net code shown above runs without the 5 lines of SQL code that created the errors, I am unable to execute the backup verification.  I'm not sure if the RESTORE FILELISTONLY is really necessary in this case.

So my question is: How do I fix things so the verification can be performed?

Comment: I'm very rusty on this stuff, but can you explain why you need to immediately restore the backup?

Comment: `USE master` has no place in that SQL because you control the database that you're connected to via the connection. If you want to switch databases, call `ChangeDatabase` on the connection, which means executing separate commands before and after.

Comment: @Hursey. In actual operation, the backup will not likely be needed immediately, but during development I'd like the backup available to restore the primary in the event various activities result in some data loss from the primary.

Comment: @jmcilhinney.  Got it re: ChangeDatabase.  And the second syntax error near 'DISK'?  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe change "RESTORE DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu]" & to "RESTORE DATABASE [conf.HelpDbBu] " & with a space at the end.